# Angular date pipe shows NaN on iphone/ios after formatting date

Tags: ios, angular, date, progressive-web-apps

I'm making a PWA on angular 8 / ionic 5. Users can create events and have them listed on a feed page. Problem is, that the `date` and the `time` of each event does not get displayed and gives the error "NaN" on iphones/iOS devices. Both `date` and `time` get their information from `start_at` which is the time in the format of "hh:mm:ss".

Following code shows how we receive the response data from our MySQL php laravel server for listing the events:

```
getTodos() {
    console.log("arrived to gettodos");
    var id = this.userInfo.id
    this.todoService.getTodos('', '', '', id, false).subscribe(res => {
      console.log("res", res);
      console.log("frimes", res['frimes']);
      // debugger;
      // console.log(res);
      if (res['code'] === 200) {
        // console.log(res['data']);
        const userFrimes: any[] = res['frimes'];
        this.todos = [] as any[];
        console.log(userFrimes);
        if (userFrimes && userFrimes.length > 0) {
          userFrimes.forEach(uf => {
            var timeofFrime = this.formatAMPM(uf.start_at);
            if (!this.todoService.isFrimeExpired(uf.start_at)) {
              this.todos.push({
                owner: this.userInfo.username,
                title: uf.title,
                message: uf.description,
                date: uf.start_at,
                time: timeofFrime,
                max: uf.max,
                guests: uf.member.length, //uf.guests == null ? 0 : uf.guests,
                frime_id: uf.id,
                status: uf.status,
                user_id: uf.user_id
              });
            }
          });
        }
      } else if (res['code'] === 205) {

      } else if (res['code'] === 401) {

      }
    }, err => {

      //this.errorMessage = err.message;
      console.log(err);
    });

  }
```

here you can see that the properties `date` and `time` are being fetched for the formatAMPM() function and changed to the AM/PM date format.

```
  formatAMPM(d) {
    let dd = d + " UTC";
    let date = new Date(dd);
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    var min = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    var strTime = hours + ':' + min + ' ' + ampm;
    return strTime;
  }
```

here the final date string gets displayed in the pipe fields where it shows the "NaN" error on ios.
the error itself says:

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "2021-05-19 17:15:38" into a date' for pipe 'Re'.

what does 'Re' mean btw?

```
            <ion-col size="3" class="date-wrapper">
              <h3 class="notification-date">
                {{ item.date | date: "shortDate" }}
              </h3>
              <h3 class="notification-date">
                {{ item.time | date: "HH:mm" }}
              </h3>
              <h3 class="notification-date">{{ item.guests + '/' + item.max }}</h3>
            </ion-col>
```

hope you can help me fixing this, because this is giving me soooo many headachse lately...
thanks in advance!

Comment: Date pipe receives a timestamp(number), Date object or ISO (https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime), double check if your string is compatible with ISO format

Comment: thank you! i believe it may not be the real problem here, because i could display the date correctly now, but within the formatAMPM() function it can't read the functions 
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i have fixed it by adding this line of code:

```
    d = d.replace(" ", "T");
```

the date came in a format like `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` and i needed to add the "T" so it is like `dd-MM-yyyyTHH:mm:ss`

```
  formatAMPM(d) {
    d = d.replace(" ", "T");
    let dd = d + " UTC";
    let date = new Date(dd);
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    var min = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    var strTime = hours + ':' + min + ' ' + ampm;
    return strTime;
  }
```